# Variable X has been used before it's been declared

Tags: vb.net

I'm not sure why I'm getting a warning from Visual Studio for the code below:

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pw.tostring)
 Try
            myconn.open
            cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Customers SET PW2=@password WHERE ID=@id", myconn)
```

This is the warning message I get:
***Severity Code Description Project File   Line    Suppression State
Warning BC42104 Variable 'Cmd' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.***
Appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the Parameters property of cmd:

```
 Dim cmd As SqlCommand
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pw.tostring) ' <== You can't use cmd yet!
```

before you instantiate it in the try:

```
  Try
        myconn.open

        ' This is where you are instantiating the object instance:
        cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Customers SET PW2=@password WHERE ID=@id", myconn)
```

If you change to this, it will work:

```
 Dim cmd As SqlCommand
 cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Customers SET PW2=@password WHERE ID=@id", myconn)

 ' You could combine the two above lines into one like this:
 'Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Customers SET PW2=@password WHERE ID=@id", myconn)

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pw.tostring)

  Try
        myconn.open
```

This is also better, because only the `myconn.open` instruction should be in the Try/Catch since it is the only line that can cause an exception.  Try/Catch should only be used around code that can cause an exception through no fault of the developer's. Adding a parameter to a command won't do that, but actual database interaction can.

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer. I learnt so much from so little code :D ps: I will accept as answer once it lets me